# Is ORDER BY on two indexed columns will be slow?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have multiple-field index on columns `a,b,c,d` and another unique index on column `id`. Is my query like below after adding `id` to `ORDER BY` slows large or i don't need to worry ? Query plan shows that sort get only 1%.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT *,
          row_number() over (
                             ORDER BY a,b,c,d,id ) AS ROW
   FROM table1
   WHERE /* ... */) a
WHERE ROW > 0
  AND ROW <= 20000;
```

[image]

Comment: It is going to depend on the number of rows, and a few other factors such as if that id column is your clustering key for that table. You should show the entire query plan (https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ is very useful for that) as that sort step may not be the only effect of the change.

Comment: index `id` is unique, multi-field index is not unique, table `table1` has about 5-10 millions records. all indexes are not clustered and created by `CREATE [UNIQUE] INDEX idx_name ...`

Answer (score 1):

If ID is the clustered index, on SQL Server this index will have ID added as the last index key.

For a non-unique non-clustered index on a clustered index table the clustered index keys that aren't explicitly listed as non-clustered index keys will be added as additional non-clustered index keys. And the non-clustered index will actually be stored as a unique index.  EG your index on (a,b,c,d) is implemented as a unique index on (a,b,c,d,id).

If the non-clustered index is unique, the clustered index keys will be present on the leaf level of the index, but will not be index keys.